# removing second portion of date time with Entity Functions

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group by on only date and hour and minute portion of date time (I don't need second), how can I achieve that. because I'm using LINQ to entity query, it seems I should use Entity Function, but it does not have proper method for this, for clarifying my need, please consider this :

```
var query = myList
    .GroupBy(s => new {s.date_time,Product_Id})
    .Select(g => new {date = g.Key.date_time, PID = g.Key.Product_Id, Count = g.Count()})
    .ToList();
```

I need something like:

```
s.date_time.AddSeconds(-s.date_time.Second)
```

in stead of

```
s.date_time
```

but it's clear it encounters exception, so I need to use Entity Functions, but it has addSeconds method but don't have second method.

by the way I'm using .net4

Answer (score 1):

If this is possible directly in EF then you *probably* will have to do it using this extension class built for various functions including those having to do with dates and times: [Entity Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(VS.100).aspx)

Maybe something like this in your group by.

```
.GroupBy(s => new {
     EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(s.date_time.Year, s.date_time.Month, s.date_time.Day, s.date_time.Hour, s.date_time.Minute, 0)
     ,Product_Id})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
.GroupBy(s => new {s.date_time.Year,s.date_time.Month...,s.date_time.Minute,Product_Id})
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.